# (find first instance of 5 digits) 'TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "re.Pattern") to str'

Tags: python, regex, python-3.7

With the below I search for for a zip-code found with 5 digits and a trailing 4 digit. i.e. `23220-3233` which works for 90% of my entries...

*HOWEVER*, a few are just 5 digit zipcodes (i.e. no XXXXX-XXXX trailing).

**How could I search for the first instance of 5 numbers together?** I am trying the below for starters; although I would need to incorporate only 'first instance'. But as of now; I am already getting '`TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "re.Pattern") to str`' on it.

```
NameNada = NameCleanST.replace("%", "")

zip_code = re.search(r'(?:[^\d]|^)(\d{5}\-\d{4})(?:[^\d]|$)', clean_content)

if zip_code:
    Zip = zip_code.group(0)[:6]

    print (NameNada)
    print(Zip)
    with open("./pdfs/TOTAL/" + NameNada + Zip + ".pdf", "wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)
else:
    zip_five = re.compile("\d{5}") # start attempt for first instance of 5 digits
    print(zip_five)
    with open("./pdfs/TOTAL/" + NameNada + zip_five + ".pdf", "wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)
```

Comment: Can you show us some sample input?  Also, when you say first instance of 5 numbers, do you mean 5 ZIP codes, or the first 5-digit only ZIP code?

Comment: Try converting the `Zip` to **str** and that would clear the error I guess

Comment: The error is because `zip_five` is a compiled regex pattern, not a string. You can concatenate the `zip_code` in the previous function because it's the string result of the `search()` function, not the pattern itself

Comment: `"./pdfs/TOTAL/" + NameNada + zip_five.group(0) + ".pdf"`

Comment: With that I'm getting: AttributeError: 're.Pattern' object has no attribute 'group'

Answer (score 1):

You could use an optional group `(?:....)?` to match the trailing part:

```
\b[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oXf8Yz/1)

Comment: No; sorry the trailing search. i.e. XXXXX-XXXX works fine. I am trying to handle entries that do not have the trailing -XXXX. So, I'm thinking the only way is to find the first instance of 5 digits; XXXXX

Comment: Oh; wait, this will handle both scenarios?

Comment: It will handle both, if you want to handle only 5 digits, you might use a negative lookahead `\b[0-9]{5}(?!-[0-9]{4})\b` https://regex101.com/r/xXOIve/1 or a more general version `(?<!\S)[0-9]{5}(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/tfPa6N/1

Comment: like this: zip_code = re.search(r'\b[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?\b', clean_content) ?

Comment: [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) will return the first match. See https://ideone.com/5FMLCc, [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) will return multiple https://ideone.com/jp1YPB